# Load new view with data - doesn't replace NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

After tap some row in UITableView apps goes to new screen. I can replace e.g. the image in UIImageView in this screen, while opening, but I defined there also NSString which cannot be replaced. Don't know why. This NSString is just defined in file .h of screenView class as NSString with @property(nonatomic,retain).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.screenView animated:YES];

self.screenView.title = @"Screen Name";
self.screenView.imageView.image = MyImage; // this work
self.screenView.MyString = @"Work?"; // but this not
}
```

Why it doesn't want to attribute a new value for NSString, while the image can be replaced this way?

Comment: Does the compiler give you an error (and in that case, what is the error?) or is it some kind of runtime problem?

Comment: No. There's no error. Just when I call NSLog with string value in screenView class, it displays (null).

Comment: Could you show the related definition/synthesize and NSLog line?

Comment: In ScreenView h. : `@interface ScreenView : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    NSString *MyString;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *MyString;` and NSLog(@"%@", MyString); I have MyString synthesized of course. Obviously class ScreenView is load as an object screenView in class for UITableView. As I said it works for picture.

Comment: OK I see why it was not working. I have called the NSLog in vievDidLoad, so it displayed me a default value (not yet replaced). I needed to call it in viewDidAppear to display this right one - changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In which method do you log MyString?

I assume you are doing this when the view is being shown or loaded, which means that the it will not contain a value since you are setting it after the push.

I would suggest to try:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
    self.screenView.title = @"Screen Name";
    self.screenView.imageView.image = MyImage; // this work
    self.screenView.MyString = @"Work?"; // but this not

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.screenView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Correct. It was that. I discovered it until you wrote, but thanks :) I loved MyString in viewDidLoad, so the data was not replaced yet. It should be loved in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{

[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.screenView animated:YES];

self.screenView.title = @"Screen Name";
self.screenView.imageView.image = MyImage; // this work
self.screenView.MyString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"Work?"];
//self.screenView.MyString = @"Work?"; // but this not
}
```